# Method to change macOS input source keyboard bindings?

Tags: keyboard, emacs, input-source

Does anyone know how to change macOS keybindings quickly?  I'm hoping to redefine the following keys:

- iMac KB Key      ->        Keycode on macOS
- CAPS LOCK       ->         Meta
- Fn -> Ctrl
- LeftCtrl       ->          Ctrl
- RightArrow       ->        Ctrl
- Modifier + g,h,j,k ->  arrow key functionality

I'm trying to redefine keys to mimic Knight and/or Symbolics LISP Machine keyboards so I can edit LISP more efficiently in Emacs.  I have considered [Karabiner-Elements](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/), [Ukelele](http://software.sil.org/ukelele/) and [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/create-and-use-your-own-input-source-on-mac-mchlp2866/mac) pages for this.  Apple appears to have XML input sources for the keyboard, however I'm unable to find them on my Mac or find the description of the XML fields in the input source document.

I tried setting the following in Keyboard preferences and it improves the situation, however I still need the arrows on the right to act as Ctrl.  It seems by placing Ctrl and Meta out on these LISP keyboards it provides a bilateral method of hand rotation for touch typing.

[image]

Any guidance appreciated.

[image: Knight]
[image: SYmbolics]
[image]